# Laravel: Composer update when dependency is not yet installed

Tags: laravel, dependencies, composer-php, service-provider

I require a dependency on my local environment. I add it's service provider and all is fine. The composer.json has this script

```
"pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
```

When I push the changes to production, I try to run composer update but because of that script artisan fails with an error since the dependency is not yet installed and therefore the service provider I added in config/app.php is not there yet.

What is the best approach to situations like this? Just remove the pre-update script?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm interesting problem

1. What are you typing in for the service provider in your app.php
2. Have you tried removing your service provider and then running `composer update` and re-adding it after the dependencies have installed?

Comment: Also, what dependency are you trying to install?

Comment: Well. It works if I remove the service provider from app.php. But the issue is how do I get past this. I am wondering how to deal with a new dependency that needs to get installed on the production server as well. Removing the pre-update-cmd solves my issue but I don't understand why it was included in the composer.json by Taylor Otwell. It does not make sense to run an artisan command before you actually update the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

*Interesting problem,*

Please **check your json file** with

`composer validate` from your working directory.